# GWT Compilation Time Performance Improvement

Tags: gwt, compilation, performance

We are using GWT Version 2.4 in our current project. On server side, we are using Spring & Custom JDBC framework.

We are using Maven as our Build Tool. The application is getting deployed on JBOSS 7 Server.

Currently we have everything in one single Eclipse Project. Means one Application.gwt.xml file and one ApplicationContext.xml for spring. We have around 2000 Java files out of which around 1500 are for GWT related source files.

The project is still growing with more source files.

We are fine with timings of Java to Javac [class file] Compilation time. But when It comes to Java to JavaScript , It is a issue.

We have used all hacks mentioned in the GWT Forum.

Like.

1. Compiling for only one Local
2. Compiling for only one Browser

But still the compilation is taking 4-6 minutes.. OR even 7 minutes some times.

With this question, I would like to know the options available to improve the same.

We are thinking to Split the Project like this WAY:

- Module 1 (JAR Build)
- Module 2 (JAR Build)
- Module Main (WAR Build). This would contain Application.gwt.xml file
  which would inherit Module 1 & Module 2.

Now Question comes:

**1) Will this help us in Improving the compilation time?**

**2) IF we change only Module 2 and then compile Module Main, will GWT still compile Module 1 as it is inherited by Module Main?**

Please share your views on above scenario. We have even tried out GWT 2.5 option but no help in performance improvements.

Thanks, Niraj Salot.

Comment: You have to isolate the problem here. Is the full compilation taking 4-6 min? or just the GWT one? Please dissociate the concepts of `GWT` module and `Maven` module in your question.

Comment: Full compilation is taking 4-6 Minutes. Means Compilation with Building WAR file.

Answer (score 1):

I 'll reply to your second question first, as it is not GWT specific. Considering your project is structured this way :

```
project-root    
  |- module1 (jar)
  |- module2 (jar)
  L moduleMain (gwt + war)
```

If you make some changes in `module2`, and do not want to recompile `module1`, you can use the option `-pl` to skip it from the build process (command to launch from the `project-root` folder):

```
mvn clean install -pl module2,moduleMain
```

This will recompile `module2`, and then `moduleMain`, without recompiling `module1`.

**Will this help us in Improving the compilation time ?**

It depends how big are `module1` and `module2` compared to `moduleMain`... But my experience with GWT is that a lot of time is generally spent to compile the java client code into javascript. This operation still occurs in your `moduleMain`, so I would say that splitting your project into several modules won't be enough to improve the compilation time significantly.

In addition, I advise you to use a profile that will control the activation/deactivation of the `gwt-maven-plugin` within `moduleMain`.

In the `moduleMain`'s pom.xml, move the GWT plugin into a profile, this way :

```
<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>GWTBuild</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.4.0</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>compile</goal>
                                    <goal>generateAsync</goal>
                                    <goal>test</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <runTarget>com.yoururlroot/index.html</runTarget>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

Then, if you just want to rebuild your war because `module2` has changed BUT whithout rebuilding `module1` AND whithout recompiling all the GWT stuff, simply launch :

```
mvn clean install -pl module2,moduleMain -P!GWTBuild
```

In this command, the GWT plugin is deactivated, so maven will only rebuild the war.

Tell me if this is working for you.

Comment: Please conside the case like this way : ModuleMain inherits module 1 and module 2. ModuleMain contains the main entry point class. Module 1 and Module 2 are just JAR with .gwt.xml file which are having no entry points. So Lets say IF I change Module1 then I need to make the JAR and install the same in Local repository using Maven. Then I  will build the WAR for ModuleMain as this will generate the final WAR for me. In this case will Module 2 compile again ? Or not? Compile means not Java to Javac but Java to Javascript...I hope this clears my question a bit.

Comment: "Please... generate the final WAR for me" => It was exactly my understanding. "In this case will Module 2 compile again ?" => no... if you follow what I explained in my post. But I don't understand your assertion "Compile means not Java to Javac but Java to Javascript"... Module2 does not contain code that is expected to be compiled in JS... Or maybe I didn't understand anything to your pb :)...

Comment: Both Module 1 and Module 2 contain code which needs to be compiled in JS.

Comment: it won't work. gwt requires to have your client code within the war. And even if it worked, you would not improve the build time significantly as you would still need to run the "compile to js" goal.

Comment: Exactly...Even If I split the Project into Multiple Modules  [GWT Modules] , I will still not be able to improve the build time...Like Java to JS generation will still happen even if I build the JAR and the finally include the JAR in WAR file with concept of Inherits...